# Retrieving part of common content of the two texts

Tags: macos, unix, sed, grep, diff

I really don't know how to proceed from the following. Suppose I have two files, `file1` and `file2`. These files consist of a long list of two entries each of which have the same structure

```
A : some text0
B : some text1

A : some text2
B : some text3

...
```

The `A` entries of `file1` and `file2` are in general the same but sometimes different, the `B` entries are totally distinct. How to retrieve in `file2` all the 'A-B' entries for which the A entry appear in `file1`?

Concrete example :

- sample of `file1`

  ```
  msgid "data0"
  msgstr ""

  msgid "data1"
  msgstr ""

  msgid "data2"
  msgstr ""
  ```
- sample of `file2`

  ```
  msgid "data0"
  msgstr "data0_t"

  msgid "data1"
  msgstr "data1_t"

  msgid "nodata2"
  msgstr "nodata2_t"
  ```

So I want the output to be a `file3`

```
msgid "data0"
msgstr "data0_t"

msgid "data1"
msgstr "data1_t"
```

Btw, I know some commands to intersect files like so :

```
for i in `cat file1 | awk {'print $1'}`
do
grep ${i} file2
done
```

but what I need is somehow more complicated

Comment: You can improve the question by providing sample input & output. Also, do all entries only occupy one line?

Comment: So the `msgstr` always has to be taken from `file2`? Are the files sorted?

Comment: yes indeed  msgstr always has to be taken from file2 but the files are not sorted

Answer (score 1):

The following command works for me with your sample:

```
grep '^msgid' file1 | while read id; do grep -A2 -e "$id" file2; done > file3
```

Comment: Might be a bit slow if the files are big.

Comment: Oups, in fact I have this message : grep: repetition-operator operand invalid

Comment: No need for the `while` just use `grep -f -` see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %seen;

$/ = ''; # Paragraph mode
open my $IN1, '<', 'file1' or die $!;
undef $seen{ (split /\n/)[0] } while <$IN1>;

open my $IN2, '<', 'file2' or die $!;
exists $seen{ (split /\n/)[0] } and print while <$IN2>;
```

Comment: excuse me I am not familiar to these kind of scripts : what do mean : my %seen;$/ = ''; (because it doesn't seem to be recognized by my shell

Comment: It is a Perl script. It shoudl be recognised by Perl.

Comment: I am using a mac, I should install perl no ?

Comment: As far as I know, Perl should be preinstalled on your Mac.

Comment: Just paste the text into a text file, save as (say) `pojoin`, then `chmod +x pojoin` and now you can `./pojoin file1 file2 >file3`. These are very fundamental operations; you'd do well to read an intro to the Unix shell if you eant to use it productively.

Answer (score 1):

if awk is accepted by you, try this one-liner:

```
awk  -F'\\n' -vRS="" 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next;} $1 in a{print $1"\n"$2"\n"}' f1 f2
```

Comment: I have this error message : awk: invalid -v option (I am using a mac)

Comment: @user1611830 tested under gnu awk. which awk version do you have? no experience with mac os. you could also try `awk -F'\\n' 'BEGIN{RS=""} NR==FNR{.......'`

Answer (score 1):

Just using `grep`:

```bsh
$ grep "^msgid" file1 | grep -A2 -f - file2
msgid "data0"
msgstr "data0_t"

msgid "data1"
msgstr "data1_t"
```

`Grep` all the `msgid` lines from `file1` and pipe these to `grep` matching lines in `file2` with the `-A1` context option to displays the line after the match as well.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's|^msgid.*|/^&/{N;N;p}|p' file1 | sed -nf - file2 > file3
```

Answer (score 0):

For `po` files, the [`msgcomm`](http://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/codes/nwprod/gempak/nawips2/os/aix5/share/doc/gettext/gettext_toc.html#TOC111) command does this.